React Native Expo - How to add media controls on lock screen without ejecting?
I am developing a mobile application for both Android & IOS which among other things it plays audio using expo-av. By changing some of the configuration variables it works even when the user locks their phone but there are no controls on the lock screen / notification screen.
After doing some research i could not find a way to enable the default controls that other apps are using (like VLC, YouTube, Spotify etc.) without ejecting from Expo and using native modules. Is it generally possible to continue with Expo and enable this functionality or should i accept it and stop using Expo ?

You can customize a popup notification
Use Expo notifications

I guess i could customize it with a play/pause button and call it a day instead of using the built-in media player. Thank you
